# How to force new `shell` to appear in current window?

Tags: window, shell, eshell, window-splitting

Whenever I run `M-x shell`, a buffer appears almost randomly somewhere - splitting current windows as it sees fit. I cannot work out the logic behind it.

The docstring says:

> `(shell &optional BUFFER)`
>
> If BUFFER exists but shell process is not running, make new shell.
>
> If BUFFER exists and shell process is running, just switch to BUFFER.

This just tells me it will open a shell if it already exists, otherwise start a new one.

I only care about the position of the buffer. If I have the window configuration set how I need it, running shell usually ruins that setup.

I did look into the source as far as I could, but am not familiar enough with the underlying eLisp.

---

I would like to have a function that splits the current window, opens a shell buffer - I perform some short operation - then I can close the newly created window, restoring the previous window configuration exactly as it was.

I have this working for `eshell`, which I stole from Howard Abrams. It looks like this:

```el
(defun eshell-here ()
  "Opens up a new shell in the directory associated with the
current buffer's file. The eshell is renamed to match that
directory to make multiple eshell windows easier."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((parent (if (buffer-file-name)
                     (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))
                   default-directory))
         (height (/ (window-total-height) 3))
         (name   (car (last (split-string parent "/" t)))))
    (split-window-vertically (- height))
    (other-window 1)
    (eshell "new")
    (rename-buffer (concat "*eshell: " name "*"))

    (insert (concat "ls"))
    (eshell-send-input)))
```

And the function to close the new buffer:

```el
(defun eshell-close ()
  "Closes the window created by the function 'eshell-here'"
  (interactive)
  (insert "exit")
  (eshell-send-input)
  (delete-window))
```

I first tried simply putting replacing `eshell` with `shell`, but that led to the random buffer positions.

Comment: As to `*shell*`, see this identical/related thread:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287

Comment: As to `*eshell*`,  see this identical/related thread:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28730/2287  You can use `my-display-buffer` (from the previous linked thread) with `eshell-get-buffer-create`.

Comment: @lawlist - Thanks for the links. Your solution: `shell-get-buffer-create` seems to work great for opening a new buffer in a predictable location. The `shell-pop` package also does a great job - like Howard Abrams `eshell-`functions I posted above.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I have for this. It opens a shell in the current window.

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("^\\*shell\\*$" . (display-buffer-same-window)))
```